# MongoDB- How to create a master template/document from an existing mongodb document collection?

Tags: mongodb, merge, nosql, mongodb-query

I am new to the mongodb. I have one mongo database which contains the around 150 collections. Currently I want to create the master document for each collection. Master document will contain all the fields in that collection. e.g. Lets say I have a users collection and it contains the two records as

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e5e384cbead107344e6420"), 
    "user_name" : "test",
    "pass" : "system",
    "email": "em@gm.com"
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e5e384cbead107344e6420"), 
    "user_name" : "test1",
    "org":{
      "name":"My Org"
    },
    "pass" : "test"
}
```

After merging the two documents I will get the master record as

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e5e384cbead107344e6420"), 
    "user_name" : "test", 
    "email" : "em@gm.com",
    "org":{
      "name":"My Org"
    },
    "pass" : "test"
}
```

Here I am not worried about the data. I need the structure of the document and data types of the fields. I have thousands of the records which are not managed properly. I need a master template which will contain the all the possible fields in all the documents of one collection. I have to create such template for each collection.

Appreciating your help.

Comment: how is it possible that, you will be having same `ObjectId` for 2 documents in mongodb?

Comment: I am not worried about the data. If data is empty then also I am fine. I just need the key and its position in the document.

Comment: I don't know whether in mongodb we can combine. My view on this would be, take the all collection data and prepare a master document by processing each and every collection using some scripting languages ...I could have done this using Python scripting and would have stored the master document  from Python for each collection.